# PHP Object Access - Video Chat Application, memcache?

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, memcached, chat

I am designing a video chat application and as of now, I have built the logic that allows users to register, and access a members area. Now I want to grab groups of users that are logged in and put them in group video chats. So as of now I have created a group video chat object that has an array with the users in the video chat (max of 4), and some more information. However I am having trouble assigning 4 users to the same video chat object. PHP instantiates a new group video chat object for each user. I think that there is something fundamental about PHP that I am not quite understanding. I thought that it had a shared memory and different users could easily access the same object. From looking online it looks like I will have to persist these group video chat objects to the database. But that doesn't feel quite right, because these group video chats are going to have a very short life span. Should I use memcache for this?

Can someone please suggest a way of doing this?

Thanks a lot in advance,

John

Comment: What's the code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a user requests a page, a new instance of apache/PHP is called. These do not share variables - think about it, if you have $user as a var in your script, then obviously it is different for each user.

You need to persist the data elsewhere. Using the database for this wouldn't be too bad, but your right in that memcached is a slightly better fit. Still, it should work pretty well no matter what storage you use.